# How can I change the black text in my terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, color

I have changed the color in my profile, but some text is still black. How can I make all black text inverted, or any color that's visible? I'm including screenshot of my preferences and the issue. The second terminal screenshot is the result of highlighting, to illustrate the problem.

[image: preferences][image: terminal]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second screen shot, it looks like you're looking at `man builtin` and the Command column, the first column, is in bold text and not visible. Looking at the Bold Text color shows it being rather dark, as dark as the Background Color & Effects in the first screen shot. So, change the Bold Text color to the same color as the Text color or just a shade darker then the Text color.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think to do that :) thank you!

Comment: For me it was the "Use bright colors for bold text" that had to be ticked.

Comment: @Zitrax, From the screenshot in the OP you can see "Use bright colors for bold text" was already checked and was obviously not working and why I suggested changing the color that was showing for Bold Text which was set to Black.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, my comment was only meant to help others in my situation - since I started out following the answer which did not work for me.